# Normal map generation - shaders and FBO

Tags: opengl, glsl, fbo, normals

I want to generate a normal map from a heightmap. I know it's a pretty 'overasked question', but I haven't found any good topics about this. The normal map should be about 6-8x larger than the original texture. I've implemented it on CPU, but this is pretty slow for a big texture, instead of it I want to do it with shaders. My idea is to render the height map to a full screen quad, and with shaders I turn it onto a normal map in fragment shader, then save the FBO texture. This could be done during init. of the map. But how can I render it with any resolution?

Lets assume the heightmap is *20,000*20,000*, then the normal map should be *160,000* * *160,000*. That's more than 25Mrd texels. For sure I would only stream a part of it to the GPU. Does the resolution of the normal map depend on the viewport or the max resolution my GPU supports, or I can make very big resolution textures?

**Is there any way of creating VERY big resolution textures on the GPU using shaders?** Now I'm calculating the normals every frame in the terrain shaders with bicubic filtering, this is extremely smooth, but since it's static mesh, it's not necessary, and also affects the performance badly.

My algorithm is to get the interpolated height, then sample 4 more around the specified height. Then a simple corss product:

```
h(x,y) //is samples 16 heigths, then interpolates them using bicubic filtering
n(x,y)
{
    h1 = h(x+offset0,y+offset0);
    ...
    v1 = (x+offset0,h1,y+offset0)
    ...
    c1 = cross(v1-v0,v2-v0)
    ...
    n = normalize(c1+c2+c3+c4)
}
```

This needs *5* * *16 = 80* samples per normal. *25,000,000,000* * *80 = 2,000,000,000,000* texelFetch for my normal map. That's seems a very big number for me, I have only made a normal map for a 4000*4000 heightmap yet (on CPU), but that was pretty slow. About how much time would it take to compute it all? On the GPU this would take ~5 minutes I think. On the CPU...I won't try.

**Do I get the same results with linear filtered heightmap lookups, then run a bicubic filter on the normal map in the end?**

I can't use a 3rd party software for this generation, I have to implement it myself using OpenGL. If it's depend on the GPU to make big resolution maps, maybe I could render a part of the normal map once, then the others.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. While I have never done anything like you describe (resampling the normal map at 8x the original resolution of the height map), I can tell you from experience that all you really need is a Sobel filter applied to the height map as an image processing step. This actually works quite well in many applications, because you can store the height maps as space saving monochrome textures and generate the normal maps at run-time using whatever image format and precision your application needs. What is more, having the original height maps available is useful for some algorithms.

Comment: One thing I don't really understand is Sobel. I've read many times that I need Sobel filtering to generate the normal map, but I can generate it with simple cross products of neighboring samples, just as I do on the fly in the fragment shader. Or is it faster?

Comment: Are you saying that presently you are generating the normal map at the same time as you are computing lighting? Generating and reusing a dedicated normal map will definitely be quicker - but for your desired resolution I think you might want to consider sparse textures, you can defer the process of computing parts of the normal map until they are first used on DX 11.2 class (or AMD HD 7xxx) hardware. It is not a standard feature yet, but they introduced an ARB extension for it with OpenGL 4.4 and it is part of DX 11.2. This is an excellent use case for that extension.

Comment: Thanks I will try that extension. And yeah, still I'm generating normals during rendering, every frame, extra smooth, but costly. That's why I want to generate one static normal map but at high resolution. Since my mesh is static this can be computed only once.